# Hide IIS version in azure when ip address entered

Tags: .net, azure, http-headers, webserver, cloud

I have a site hosted with an azure webapp but cannot hide the iis version on 404 web site not found pages. For example a user can simply ping the website and get the ip, then using that ip address will now give the iis version.

Is there anyway in azure to prevent this showing? i have not found any where that allows you to adjust iis settings within azure.

Thanks for any help

*Update: *It appears you can generate a static ip address by adding an ssl certificate and binding it by IP. Before i buy the ssl certificate has anyone else used this method? and will the ip resolve to the site?*

Answer (score 0):

You can now hide the `Server` and `X-Powered-By` headers by adding an entry to your `web.config` in `system.webServer` node:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering removeServerHeader ="true" />
</security>
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://www.saotn.org/remove-iis-server-version-http-response-header/).

Comment: I am already doing this, the server can be hidden. But because entering an ip address goes to the 404 page it seems to bypass the web config settings